# JavaScript why doesn't return exit the encompassing function call?

Tags: javascript, reactjs

so I'm pretty new to JS and coming from a background of C++ this language really confuses me. I'm having an issue understanding how the return statement and the if/else statements actually function in the code below:

```
makeGroup= (formGroup) => {
     //checking for duplicate users
    existsInDatabase(this.context.user, formGroup.name).then(
        (result) => {
            if(result != null){
                if(result.group !== formGroup.group){
                    this.setState({
                        showAlert: true,
                        //alert message
                    });
                    return;
                }
            }
        }
    )

    if(this.state.showAlert == true){
        console.log("test");
        return;
    }

    else if (/*group has no members*/) {
        this.setState({
           showAlert: true,
           //alert message
        });
        return;
    }

    else{
        //do something
    }
}
```

In this code, the program enters the first if statement and prints out "test" to the console as expected. However, it doesn't return and just exit the function. Instead, it moves to the else if statement, executes it, and then moves on to the else statement. First of all, why didn't the initial return statement just straight up exit the function??? If the if statement evaluates to false and the else if statement is true, the return statement exists the function as expected?? Also, why does it move onto the else if and then the else statement if the if statement has already been executed?

I'm stumped.

Comment: Your `this.state.showAlert == true` test is going to execute *before* the initial `this.setState(showAlert: true)` executes because the latter happens in an asynchronous callback that happens later. That said, if it console logs "test" then it will return from the `makeGroup()` function.

Comment: @jarmod Ah okay that makes sense, thanks so much for the help. To fix the issue I just put the rest of the content after the async call into another function, and called it inside the then() scope so that it only executed after the response was fetched.